# Holder for 75 mm x 25 mm glass slides that can handle vibration

Tags: molecular-biology

Hello Biology Stack Exchange,

I have an application where I have cells on a glass slide (dimensions: standard 75 mm length x 25 mm width  x 1 mm thick).  I want to vibrate/shake the cells rapidly while viewing through a microscope.

I have a piece of equipment that can produce vibrations, I just need to connect it to the glass slide somehow.

Are there any holders for glass slides out there that:

- Firmly hold the glass slide
- Enable me to somehow connect vibration equipment with the slide?  (Ex: screw into the holder, glue onto the holder, clamp onto the holder)
- And still view the slides contents under a microscope?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE!  I'm skeptical that you will be able to image actively vibrating cells, but that clearly depends on what sort of frequencies you are interested in (and your cameras frame rate/shutter speed).  Can you add more of that sort of detail to your question and maybe why you want to do this?  Also, have you considered using ultrasound to produce the vibrations?

Comment: @tyersome thank you for pointing out ultrasound!  Not bad thinking.  Per imaging active cells, I have previously adhered vibration motors directly onto glass slides, and I was still able to make out what was happening on the slide, even though it was very chaotic.